# Get Pepper robot tells the time and date

Tags: text-to-speech, pepper, choregraphe

I would like to create a simple program, with the objective to get Pepper tells me the time or the date now, when it recognizes my speech, either "Date" or "Time" in my case. May I know how should I code in my TTS python script?

Below is the code on my TTS python box:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
def __init__(self):
    GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

def onLoad(self):
    #put initialization code here
    from naoqi import ALProxy


    self.tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech")

    pass

def onUnload(self):
    #put clean-up code here
    pass

def onInput_onStart(self):
    #self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
    self.tts.say("Today is **#here i want to get input from GET DATE box#** ")
    self.onStopped()
    pass

def onInput_onStop(self):
    self.onUnload() #it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped
    self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```

[Print screen of my Choregraphe program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW1SP.png)

Thanks everyone for help. I'm beginner here.

Answer (score 1):

Pepper is like any (linux) computer system programmable in python. As for all thoses system, you should use the date and time library.

Have a look at the reference there: https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/datetime.html